# Laravel array group by and merge each group

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-collection

I have such an array, how can I group by `date` and merge each group?

```
$input =  [
    [
        'date' => '2018-09-25',
        'foo' => 'value1',
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2018-09-25',
        'bar' => 'value2'
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2018-09-26',
        'baz' => 'value3'
    ]
];
```

That in the end it turned out like this:

```
[
    [
        'date' => '2018-09-25'
        'foo' => 'value1'
        'bar' => 'value2'
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2018-09-26'
        'baz' => 'value3'
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use laravel [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections).

First you need to group by [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-groupby) method, then [map](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-map) each group and merge every child array.

Code:

```
$result = collect($input)
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->map(function ($item) {
        return array_merge(...$item->toArray());
    });
```

You will get this collection:

[image]

And in the end remove the keys(date), you can use [values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-values), and simply convert the collection to an array([toArray](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-toarray)).

End Code:

```
$result = collect($input)
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->map(function ($item) {
        return array_merge(...$item->toArray());
    })
    ->values()
    ->toArray();
```