# PHP array merge with conditions

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Basically I have two arrays.

[image]

From index 0 to 9 are my first, and 10 to 20 is the second. What I want is merge or put the array in the first one if they have the same `users_mws_id` but what I get is the one in the picture. What I tried is

```
                foreach($newArr as $arr){
                    $res = DB::table('admin_case_info')
                    ->where('users_mws_id',$arr->users_mws_id)
                    ->where(function($q){
                        $q->orWhereIn('issue_type',['damaged2','lost2 ','disposed_of_dse','disposed_of_inb'])
                            ->orWhereIn('case_type',['ORDER_NEVER_RETURNED','ORDER_RETURNED_WITH_INCORRECT_FNSKU','OTHER_CONCESSIONS_GOODWILL','INBOUND_SHIPMENT'])
                            ->orWhereNull('case_type')
                            ->orWhereNull('issue_type')
                            ->whereNotIn('case_status',['CLOSED','ACI']);
                            
                    })
                    ->select('users_mws_id')
                    ->selectRaw('sum(pending) as pending,sum(approved) as approved,sum(rejected) as rejected',)->get()->toArray();
        
                    foreach($res as $d){
                        if($arr->users_mws_id === $d->users_mws_id){
                            array_push($newArr,$d);
                        }
                    }
                }
                dd($newArr);
```

`$newArr` is my main Array. Can someone tell me what I missed or need to do? Thanks.

EDIT. `$newArr` is from this query

```
            $users = DB::query()->select(
                'mws_name',
                DB::raw('MAX(created_at) as created_at'),
                'updated_at',
                'users_mws_id'
            )
                ->fromSub(function ($query) {
                    $query->select([
                        'um.mws_name',
                        'ac.users_mws_id',
                        'ac.case_type',
                        'ac.created_at',
                        'ac.pending',
                        'ac.approved',
                        'ac.rejected',
                        'ac.updated_at',
                        'ac.issue_type',
                        'um.user_type',
                    ])->from('admin_case_info as ac')
                    ->join('users_mws as um', 'ac.users_mws_id', '=', 'um.id')
                    ->join('users','users.id','=','um.user_id')
                    ->whereNotIn('users.status',['Dumped','Dumped2'])
                    ->where('users.user_type','user')
                    ->where('um.user_type','user')
                    ->where(function($q){
                        $q->orWhereIn('ac.issue_type',['damaged2','lost2 ','disposed_of_dse','disposed_of_inb'])
                            ->orWhereIn('ac.case_type',['ORDER_NEVER_RETURNED','ORDER_RETURNED_WITH_INCORRECT_FNSKU','OTHER_CONCESSIONS_GOODWILL','INBOUND_SHIPMENT'])

                            ->whereNotIn('ac.case_status',['CLOSED','ACI']);    
                    })
                    ->whereNull('ac.deleted_at');
                }, 'acum')
                ->groupBy('acum.users_mws_id')
                ->orderByRaw('MAX(acum.created_at) asc')
                ->limit(10)
                ->get();
                // dd($users);
                // ->toSql();
                
                $newArr = [];
                foreach ($users as $key => $u){
                    $newArr[] = $u;
                }
```

Comment: What is `$newArr`?

Comment: `$newArr` is the array from 0-9 from the picture. @BABAKASHRAFI

Comment: Your graphic does a poor job of representing your exact desired output from the graphic input.  Please provide a [mcve] that does not offer text in graphics.  Array you simply trying to `array_chunk()` your data? "_PHP array merge with conditions_" is a very vague title that would apply to hundreds of pages here.  Can you improve your question title?

Comment: use UNION to merge it,.

Comment: Are you asking how to groupby and sum your data?  If you are able to collect all of the targeted data and you just need to restructure it, then show us your data as `var_export()` instead of `dd()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel array group by and merge each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52485528/laravel-array-group-by-and-merge-each-group)

Answer (score 1):

Below is what you were after however, This would cause a massive amount of queries.

You should be doing it as a relation, also thats if the newArr is actually a collection, if not make it one.

```
$stuff = collect($newArr)->map(function($item) {
    $res = DB::table('admin_case_info')
        ->where('users_mws_id', $item->users_mws_id)
        ->where(function($q){
            $q->orWhereIn('issue_type',['damaged2','lost2 ','disposed_of_dse','disposed_of_inb'])
                ->orWhereIn('case_type',['ORDER_NEVER_RETURNED','ORDER_RETURNED_WITH_INCORRECT_FNSKU','OTHER_CONCESSIONS_GOODWILL','INBOUND_SHIPMENT'])
                ->orWhereNull('case_type')
                ->orWhereNull('issue_type')
                ->whereNotIn('case_status',['CLOSED','ACI']);
                
        })
        ->select('users_mws_id')
        ->selectRaw('sum(pending) as pending,sum(approved) as approved,sum(rejected) as rejected',)->get()->toArray();
        
        return array_merge($item, $res);
});
```

Please show us the model of your `$newArr`, This is a simple relation. we can return it all in one go.

Comment: im getting `Call to a member function map() on array `

Comment: @KIKOSoftware you get used to it spending a whole day looking at questions on stack overflow.

Comment: @draw134 updated answer, this is because it was actually an array not a collection.

Comment: okay. but now it returns `Call to undefined method stdClass::push() `

Comment: @draw134 then array merge or combine or create a new array. - updated answer

Comment: `$newArr` is from query I just loop it inside new array which is `newArr`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231351/discussion-between-draw134-and-michael-mano).

Answer (score 0):

You can group the result of `newArr` after your codes based on `users_mws_id`

```
collect($newArr)->groupBy('users_mws_id');
```

Comment: do i need to put this inside the loop right sir?

Comment: No. after the loop

Comment: in the first loop? or in the second one with the condition

Comment: ya. tried it but it only outputs the original values of `$newArr`

Comment: It'll group your result based on your desired key. refer to [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby)

Comment: but how about the query? I need the sum values for it

Comment: If this is the answer, then this page should be closed as a duplicate, right?  Please vote to close instead of answering.

Comment: @mickmackusa I will